# Can port number get masked like IP?

Tags: ip, port, public-key

I have one IP address which looks like this 10.0.0.1:9095 and as far as I know HTTP can only use port 80. How is this masked URL working?

Comment: HTTP is not restricted to port 80. That is only a convention. Most ports can be configured to serve HTTP in the web server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

On the server side, the service (httpd, for instance) opens a port, and listens for communications on it. the service can listen on any port that is not presently in use on the system.

[IANA](http://www.iana.org/) provides guidelines on [port](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) usage, and allowed well known protocols to reserve ports for use, HTTP [80], FTP [20,21], and SMTP [25] for instance.

[Well Known ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports) are those below 1024, and are generally expected to carry the protocol indicated. remember any port can carry any protocol, but some network intermediary devices may make management decisions based on these ports.

[Registered ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Registered_ports) are between 1024 and 49151, and can be reserved for internet applications. There are many unregistered ports in this range, and many network admins choose to use them when selecting alternate ports for services to run on. As you can see from the link above, ports 9094-9099 are unreserved, making them a perfect choice.

Ports above 49151 are called [Dynamic Ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Dynamic.2C_private_or_ephemeral_ports), and cannot be registered for any particular use. many ISPs block them all together. don't use them for service hosting.

**TL;DR:**
The admin of the site at that link choose to use an unreserved port from the Registered range. 9094-9099 are unreserved, and can be used for whatever purpose without confusion.